# Using Option Pattern with Azure Key Vault?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, azure-keyvault

I have Azure Key Vault successfully working on my web app, and I am able to access the secrets using `_config["foo"]`
, but I was curious if there is a way to implement the Options pattern with Azure Key Vault.  I currently have my AppSettings.json bound to a class using:

```
services.Configure<AppSettings>(o => 
configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").Bind(o));
```

But I am unable to find the correct "Section" I should be using to bind azure key vault secrets.  Is this possible, or is this a feature that has not been implemented yet?

Answer (score 2):

To anyone in the future that may have this issue, the answer is simpler than I thought, though I am still unsure of how exactly it is working under the covers.
`services.Configure<AzureSettings>(Configuration);`
Is all that is needed, with AzureSettings having the corresponding properties to each key vault secret that is coming in.

Comment: Thanks, this actually helped mine. Just worth mentioning that AzureSettings is your custom Settings file.

Answer (score 1):

File this answer under "I got it to work" but I welcome comments on better ways to use Azure Key Vault secrets, especially since the online examples I found are not consistent.

First, I am using Visual Studio 2019. It has a setting for development authentication as described here:

[Service-to-service authentication to Azure Key Vault using .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/service-to-service-authentication)

There are many ways to authenticate. I have only tried the Visual Studio technique, but once you have that working it shouldn't be to hard to figure out how to use the other methods. I have not tried the code below in production even though I have a guard in the code for the production environment. I just inverted the logic to test the key vault in my development environment. With that said, here is what I did:

Install these NuGet packages:

- **Azure.Identity**
- **Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault**

Note: The link above indicates this package is obsolete even though it is mentioned in the same article:

- Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication

so don't install it.

In my web api .Net Core 3.1 app, the Program class code has the additional **ConfigureAppConfiguration()** call:

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((ctx, builder) =>
                {
                    if (ctx.HostingEnvironment.IsProduction())
                    {
                        var config = builder.Build();

                        var tokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();

                        var kvClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(tokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));

                        builder.AddAzureKeyVault(config["KeyVault:BaseUrl"], kvClient, new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());
                    }
                })
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

Note: If you want to test this in development instead of using the secrets.json settings change this line:

```
if (ctx.HostingEnvironment.IsProduction())
```

to

```
if (!ctx.HostingEnvironment.IsProduction())
```

Side note: In Visual Studio, right click on your project and click on "Manage User Secrets" or use the dotnet CLI user-secrets command to manage them. The Key Vault settings will override the secrets.json settings.

My appsettings.json file has this section:

```
"KeyVault": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://mykeyvaultname.vault.azure.net/",
    "Secrets": {
      "Secret1": "foo",
      "Secret2": "bar"
    }
  },
```

Note this line in program.cs matches the KeyVault section location:

```
builder.AddAzureKeyVault(config["KeyVault:BaseUrl"], kvClient, new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());
```

Read this tutorial about the Key Vault to learn how to set secrets:

[Tutorial: Use Key Vault references in an ASP.NET Core app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/use-key-vault-references-dotnet-core?tabs=powershell%2Ccore3x)

I created two classes to match two different configurations. The first one only matches secrets in the key vault. The second matches they key vault and the appsettings file but the key vault  secrets take precedence:

This class only matches two secrets in my key vault, "MySecretKey and "MyOtherSecretKey"

```
    public class KeyVaultSettingsModel
    {
        public string MyOtherSecretKey { get; set; }
        public string MySecretKey { get; set; }
    }
```

and another class that matches the "KeyVault:Secrets" path in the appsettings.json file:

```
public class KeyVaultSettingsModel1
{
    public string Secret1 { get; set; }
    public string Secret2 { get; set; }
}
```

If you have nested values in the appsettings file, your secret name in the key vault has to match it. But you have to replace the ":" character with "--". That means your secret name has to be of the form:

```
KeyVault--Secrets--Secret1
```

**NOT**

```
KeyVault:Secrets:Secret1
```

Once you have the above configured, you can use the Options pattern. In Startup.cs, configure your models above for use with the IOptions* interfaces and use DI to access them where needed.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // other code
    
    services.Configure<KeyVaultSettingsModel>(Configuration);
    services.Configure<KeyVaultSettingsModel1>(Configuration.GetSection("KeyVault:Secrets"));
    
    // other code
}
```